# How do I add a link to a class using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, class, hyperlink

Please bear with me; Im very new to JS- as in barely started a beginners course.

I know this is possible in html, but I want to know if its doable in js.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
const link = document.querySelector(`.logoImg`);
a.href(link) = `https://website.com`;
```

Sorry if this is infuriatingly simple but I can't seem to see where i'm going wrong, thanks in advance!

EDIT: .logoImg is a class that already exists, that I want to add the link to.

Comment: you're inverting the variable and the attribute

Comment: Firstly, your syntax isn't quite right. You need to get a property from `.logoImg` element - I would assume its `src` - as appending the entire Element object to a string won't work as you seem to expect. Your last line which sets the `href` should then be `a.setAttribute('href', link);`. Secondly, your title doesn't make a lot of sense - do you mean instead that you're trying to add a `class` attribute/value to the `<a>` element you create?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: when you say `I know this is possible in html`, how would you do that in html?

Comment: Given your update, could you please provide 1) a written description of what you're trying to do, as the code alone isn't clear enough. 2) A sample of the initial HTML

Answer (score 1):

`var a = document.createElement('a');` gives you an element (a brand new `<a>` that isn't attached to the DOM yet).

`` const link = document.querySelector(`.logoImg`); `` also gives you an element (assuming that the selector matched something in the document) which is already in the DOM.

Now you have **two** variables pointing to two different elements.

You probably only want one of those two lines. Which one depends on which of the elements you want to modify.

---

`a.href(link)` is nonsense. It takes the `href` of the newly created element (off the top of my head I can't remember if it is `undefined` or `''` by default) and tries to execute it as a function (passing `link` as an argument). Neither `undefined` nor `''` is a function so this will error.

You need `a.href =` or `link.href =` depending on which element you want modify the `href` property of.

---

Things get more complicated if the element with `class="logoImg"` isn't a `<a>` but something else that you want to put inside a new `<a>`.